# DYNAMIC QUERIES in GCP Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to execute this dynamic query in GCP bigquery.

`` EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO `project.dataset.tbl` (MARKET, PARAMETERS, KPI, VALUE_TYPE,  `03_2023`,    `04_2023`,  `05_2023`,  `06_2023`,  `07_2023`,  `08_2023`,  `09_2023`,  `10_2023`,  `11_2023`,  `12_2023`,  `01_2024`,  `02_2024`,  `03_2024`,  `04_2024`,  `05_2024`,  `06_2024`,  `07_2024`,  `08_2024`,  `09_2024`,  `10_2024`,  `11_2024`,  `12_2024`,  `01_2025`,  `02_2025`,  `03_2025`,  `04_2025`, HIST_DATE) SELECT A.MARKET, A.PARAMETERS, A.KPI, A.VALUE_TYPE,  @A , @B ,cast(FORMAT_DATE(\'%Y-%m-%d\',@LD)as date) FROM ( SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.tbl`      WHERE LAST_DAY(HIST_DATE) = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(cast(FORMAT_DATE(\'%Y-%m-%d\',@LD)as date),INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) ) AS A         INNER JOIN `project.dataset.tbl2` AS B ON A.MARKET = B.MARKET AND A.PARAMETERS = B.PARAMETERS       AND A.KPI = B.KPI AND A.VALUE_TYPE = B.VALUE_TYPE' USING COLUMN_A AS A,COLUMN_B AS B, LAST_DATE AS LD; ``

The value of column_A is `A.03_2023, A.04_2023, A.05_2023, A.06_2023, A.07_2023, A.08_2023, A.09_2023, A.10_2023, A.11_2023` which is replacing @A in the dynamic query.
While the value of column_B is `B.12_2023, B.01_2024, B.02_2024, B.03_2024, B.04_2024, B.05_2024, B.06_2024, B.07_2024, B.08_2024, B.09_2024, B.10_2024, B.11_2024, B.12_2024, B.01_2025, B.02_2025, B.03_2025, B.04_2025` which is replacing @B in the dynamic query.

However, the insert fails saying that the select returns only 7 rows while insert has 31 expected.
What do I do so it takes the @A is replaced with the value of COLUMN_A and @B is replaced with column_B and the total is 31 columns?

Comment: Does `@A` consists of a struct or an array of struct? Adding a `.*` after the A, will unstruct it. `Declare  A  struct<y INT64,a INT64>;
SET A = (Select struct(45 as y,789 as x) as a);
 Select A.*`

Comment: Hi Thanks, The @A is place holder where I wanted to put the sting present in COLUMN_A  variable of string data type.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to put the string value present in my COLUMN_A variable.
The FROM clause did the trick. I did not include @A as a place-holder in the solution. Simply put a concatenation break using '||A_COLUMN_NAME||'.
A_COLUMN_NAME field of table STRING_AGGREGATED_COLUMNS has the string I was trying to substitute previously using @A.

```
set COLUMN_NAME_QUERY =(select  'INSERT INTO `project.dataset.tbl`  (MARKET, PARAMETERS, KPI, VALUE_TYPE,  `03_2023`,    `04_2023`,  `05_2023`,  `06_2023`,  `07_2023`,  `08_2023`,  `09_2023`,  `10_2023`,  `11_2023`,  `12_2023`,  `01_2024`,  `02_2024`,  `03_2024`,  `04_2024`,  `05_2024`,  `06_2024`,  `07_2024`,  `08_2024`,  `09_2024`,  `10_2024`,  `11_2024`,  `12_2024`,  `01_2025`,  `02_2025`,  `03_2025`,  `04_2025`, HIST_DATE) SELECT A.MARKET, A.PARAMETERS, A.KPI, A.VALUE_TYPE, '||A_COLUMN_NAME||','||B_COLUMN_NAME||' ,cast(FORMAT_DATE(\'%Y-%m-%d\','||LAST_DATE||')as date) FROM ( SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.tbl`       WHERE LAST_DAY(HIST_DATE) = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(cast(FORMAT_DATE(\'%Y-%m-%d\','|| LAST_DATE || ')as date),INTERVAL -1 MONTH))) AS A INNER JOIN `project.dataset.tbl2`  AS B ON A.MARKET = B.MARKET AND A.PARAMETERS = B.PARAMETERS        AND A.KPI = B.KPI AND A.VALUE_TYPE = B.VALUE_TYPE' 
from STRING_AGGREGATED_COLUMNS);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (COLUMN_NAME_QUERY);
```